# Red Hat 9: Webmin Port 10000 not accesable

Tags: redhat, rhel, webmin

I use(d) to work with Debian and Ubuntu and never had this problems before when trying to install Webmin

```
hostnamectl
```

> Static hostname: mach04
> Icon name: computer-vm
> Chassis: vm 
> Machine ID: 22265329c8c54819a50d0509f264c692
> Boot ID: ad4aa5a62e454ef4b07ee1b54e15aaf8
> Virtualization: oracle
> Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.1 (Plow)
> CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos
> Kernel: Linux 5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.x86_64
> Architecture: x86-64
> Hardware Vendor: innotek GmbH
> Hardware Model: VirtualBox

I did the following to install Webmin

```
sudo dnf install webmin
```

Now, of course I get this message

> Dependencies resolved.
> Nothing to do.
> Complete!

So, I guess that Webmin is installed correctly.

```
sudo rpm -qa | grep webmin
```

> webmin-2.013-1.noarch

```
systemctl status webmin | grep Active
```

> Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-02-24 11:41:48 CET; 1h 8min ago

So far, so good. But now come the problems.

I can't access Webmin via browser. https://mach04:10000/ gives me a time out.

I am working with PuTTy/SSH, so it's not a network issue. I can reach the host.

I guess it might be a problem with firewall settings. Please take into account that I am using a fresh install of Red Hat, so no changes to firewall settings had been done by me.

I can't find Webmin in list of allowed services.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all | grep webmin # empty result
```

When trying to add webmin service to the filewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=webmin
```

> Error: INVALID_SERVICE: webmin

It looks like webmin is not available as a service

```
sudo firewall-cmd --get-services | grep webmin # empty result
```

Firewalld is up and running

```
systemctl status firewalld | grep active
```

> Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-02-24 11:41:48 CET; 1h 19min ago

But there is an error showing up as well

```
systemctl status firewalld | grep webmin
```

> Feb 24 11:44:00 mach04 firewalld[800]: ERROR: INVALID_SERVICE: webmin
> Feb 24 11:46:48 mach04 firewalld[800]: ERROR: INVALID_SERVICE: webmin
> Feb 24 12:56:55 mach04 firewalld[800]: ERROR: INVALID_SERVICE: webmin

This is netstatt

```
netstat -apn|grep -w 10000
```

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           -

What now? Who can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=10000/tcp --zone=public --permanent
sudo  firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now http://mach04:10000/ works. But somehow I don't feel good about it because netstat shows no difference.

```
sudo netstat -pnltu | grep 10000
```

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      887/perl
> udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           887/perl